# Re-importing Modules into IntelliJ

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I am having trouble re-importing previously imported and removed maven modules on IntelliJ. The only way I am able to import them is by renaming them (changing folder names), which I don't want to do. When I go through the wizard I get the message: Unable to proceed. Nothing found to import. My project is grayed out in the Window that says select Maven project to import. I am guessing IntelliJ caches names of imported modules somewhere and doesn't purge them when you remove the modules. Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 63):

This happened to me as well, what I did:

Go to File > Settings > Maven > Ignored Files and uncheck the ignored files.

Then re-import the module, shouldn't be greyed out anymore.

EL

Comment: Worked for me too.  That's odd behavior. When I add a maven module to a project through the Intellij wizard it gets ignored? Whatever JetBrains.

Answer (score 17):

Are you aware of this button on the Maven tab?  It may fix your issue.

[image]

Also, this may be a cache issue.  You can clear your cache by clicking File -> Invalidate Caches...

Other than that I do not have enough information to help you.  If you had steps to reproduce this issue that would help a lot.

Comment: Switching around different branches, Intellij gets confused as to which artifacts it needs to read, sometimes due to failing Auto-Import of Modules. This button is the magic wand! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this in IntelliJ 2016.3 by right-clicking relevant pom.xml file and selecting: Maven > Unignore Projects

Reimport all Maven projects does not change its status.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could not import because maven item was absent:

[image]

How to fix: Maven Integration Extension - **restart** (Enable)

Answer (score 0):

As tieTYT said, On Mac OSX, IJ 12.1.4, if you tilt your head to the right, you should see a **Maven Projects** tab, click on that. There will be a blue refresh button which would say 'reimport all maven projects'. That's the one.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was in debug mode, even without active breakpoint.
So, interrupt debug mode may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Above did not work for me.
This is what worked:
Right click on the pom.xml and choose option to "Mark as XML".